# How to pass Node values dynamically one after one?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, bpel

This is my XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <process>
     <Object>
        <Name>Rasi</Name>
        <Age>28</Age>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
     </Object>
     <Object>
        <Name>Kahanna</Name>
        <Age>32</Age>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
     </Object>
     <Object>
        <Name>jagat</Name>
        <Age>22</Age>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
     </Object>
     <Object>
        <Name>zuvari</Name>
        <Age>32</Age>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
     </Object>
  </process>
```

I want to pass these node[] values one after one. I mean it will insert these values into my database, but first I want to insert only `<object[1]>` then after successfully inserted again my XSLT will insert the next `<object[2]>` values like that depend on my input.
So here is my question: how can I pass the `<object[]>` value dynamically in XSLT. If I use `for-each` at a time all record will pass, some times need to pass particular node set values only. If hardcore like below

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <top:Collections>
     <top:username>
      <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:process/ns1:Object[1]/ns1:Name"/>
    </top:username>
    <top:firstname>
      <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:process/ns1:Object[1]/ns1:Age"/>
    </top:firstname>
    <top:lastname>
      <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:process/ns1:Object[1]/ns1:Gender"/>
    </top:lastname>
 </top:collections> 
</xsl:template>
```

Every time it will insert first `<object>` values only.

Comment: What does the desired output look like?

Comment: i want output like 

 `<Object>
        <Name>jagat</Name>
        <Age>22</age>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
     </Object> ` 

but i don't want use this below statement in my xslt
`<xsl:value-of select="/ns1:process/ns1:Object[3]/ns1:Name"/>
<xsl:value-of select="/ns1:process/ns1:Object[3]/ns1:Age"/>
<xsl:value-of select="/ns1:process/ns1:Object[3]/ns1:Gender"/>`

so help me on passing value dynamically .

Comment: @zx485: I wonder if your edit to this post might mask the problem. If the OP is opening with a camel-case tag and closing with a lower-case tag, shouldn't readers see that?

Comment: @halfer: Hmm. I was editing this for others to have an easier going to approach this question. Without my edit this wasn't even well-formed XML. **Every** XML parser would immediately reply that this was erroneous, because the identity of opening tags and closing tags is the basis of XML. So I didn't assume that this may have been an issue. Insisting on it, I should rather have removed the `xml` tag from the question ;-)

Comment: @zx485: thanks. Well, let's leave it for now - at least our comments will help either the OP, or readers who wish to answer. However in future it may be worth checking with the poster in case of serious errors like this. I've no idea how they could creep in to be honest - why would someone type in XML when they can more easily paste it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an XSLT processor which can pass parameters to the stylesheet like `xsltproc`, you can use the following approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:param name="objNum" select="'1'" />

  <xsl:template match="/process">
    <xsl:copy-of select="Object[position() = $objNum]" />
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When, for example, called with `xsltproc` with a parameter of the object number like this:

```
xsltproc --param objNum 3 this.xslt input.xml
```

you get the third object as the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Object>
    <Name>jagat</Name>
    <Age>22</Age>
    <Gender>M</Gender>
</Object>
```

You could then include the call to `xsltproc` in a shell script(this is for linux, but windows is also possible):

```
#!/bin/bash
count=1
while [ $count -le 4 ]
do
  xsltproc --param objNum $count this.xslt input.xml
  echo "---"
  count=`expr $count + 1`
done
```

This separately gives all four objects separated by '---'.

Comment: I tried it in below way and its working fine, passing the value in to ojjNum variable

Comment: `<xsl:param name="objNum" select="1"/>`
  `<xsl:template match="/">`
    `<top:Person>`
        `<top:FirstName>`
          `<xsl:value-of select="/ns1:process/ns1:Object[position() = $objNum]/ns1:Name"/>`
        `</top:FirstName>`
         `<top:DOB>`
          `<xsl:value-of select="/ns1:process/ns1:Object[position() = $objNum]/ns1:Age"/>`
        `</top:DOB>`
        `<top:Gender>`
          `<xsl:value-of select="/ns1:process/ns1:Object[position() = $objNum]/ns1:Gender"/>`
        `</top:Gender>`
    `</top:Person>`
      `</top:FeedCollection>`
      `</xsl:template>`
`</xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: It's great that my solution seems to be working fine. However, my solution was relating to the comment above below your question which suggested the style of the result. So I used `<Object>` tags instead of `<ns1:Object>` tags to answer your question. If you liked my answer, I would appreciate you accepting it. Otherwise I could modify my answer to fit your special needs to make it perfectly appropriate. Please tell me your decision.

Comment: Really appreciate you for your quick response on this issue. I really want to say thanks a lot  such giving a simple and clear solutions.